# dig nameserver domain | $variable doesn't work

Tags: bash, variables, parentheses, dollar-sign, dig

What am I doing wrong?

This works:

```
ns="ns.nameserver.co.uk"
d="domain.co.uk"
dig @$ns $d A | grep $d
```

However using just a variable after pipe does not (it hangs):

```
ns="ns.nameserver.co.uk"
d="domain.co.uk"
g=$(grep $d | grep -v "DiG")
dig @$ns $d A | $g
```

Do I need to do something special after the pipe so it knows to run the grep command from the g variable? Using backticks (historic) fails as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eval

```
ns="ns.nameserver.co.uk"
d="domain.co.uk"
g="grep $d | grep -v 'DiG'"
dig @$ns $d A | eval $g
```

Comment: Eval almost works, however it doesn't like doing grep then a pipe then another command inside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store a command in a variable, only the *output* of a command. Since you haven't specified any input to `grep` on the third line, it will read from standard input. You can simply remove the variable and change the `dig` command to the following

```
dig @$ns $d A | grep $d | grep -v "DiG"
```

Comment: I thought so. It was just because I have it to look for A, AAAA, MX and TXT so I wanted to have one variable to edit (more clean) instead of all four greps to have | grep -v 'DiG\|;' after them.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function instead of a variable.

```
ns="ns.nameserver.co.uk"
d="domain.co.uk"
g () {
    grep "$1" | grep -v "DiG"
}
dig @$ns $d A | g "$d"
```

Comment: This doesn't work either, just returns: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Are you trying to put the function definition on one line? If so, a semi-colon is required between the command and the closing brace.

Comment: Ah, I had a feeling that would be necessary. Will give it a go even though I have found a solution :) tah.